# How to show result based on other columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to show improve or decreased in one column based on two other column

```
select * from tbl_employee where empid='77' and age> 30
```

If day target - submitted links is greater than 1 it should show not reached and vice versa. performance- reached/not reached instead of showing number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `case`:

```
select c.Categoryname, DayTarget, l.LnkSubmsnDate, l.LnkSubmtdBy,
       COUNT(LinkId) as submittedLinks,
       (DayTarget - COUNT(LinkId)) as performance,
       (case when DayTarget > COUNT(LinkId) then 'NotReached'
             else 'Reached'
        end) as MadeIt
from tbl_Link l left join
     Tbl_DaySubmission ds
     on l.ProjectId = ds.projectid and l.CategoryId = ds.CatId left join
     tbl_Category c
     on l.CategoryId = c.CategoryId
where LnkSubmsnDate = '2015-10-10' and l.ProjectId = '109'
group by c.Categoryname, ds.DayTarget, LnkSubmsnDate, l.LnkSubmtdBy;
```

If you don't want the actual number, then remove the `performance` column.